# Missing numpy dependency

Tags: python, matlab, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to build a  python script that is suppose to feed into another Matlab program. the script uses (among other things) numpy and pandas.
Here's the matlab code when I try to load the script:

```
path='C:\XXXXXX\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe';
pyversion(path)
algo=py.importlib.import_module('Algo_Pres');
```

When I try to load the script into matlab, I get an import error that seems to originate from python:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I understand the error as: pandas is missing a numpy dependency.

And yet when I turn back to python and run the script in python it works smoothly...

Where do you think the problem comes from?

PS: I checked my Library using conda list in the Prompt.
For some reason numpy is listed in the anaconda channel, whereas anything else is listed without any channel. Do you think it could be linked?

Comment: What Python version is Matlab using and what version are you using when running the script directly?

Comment: When I use matlab  it's 3.6:

        pyversion
        version: '3.6'
Since I'm using Anconda I can't tell for sure, but spyder seems to be 3.3.1

Comment: What are you doing when you are running the script directly, what version is it then? Your problem seems to be caused by having two (or more) Python installations and the one Matlab is using does not have numpy installed but the other one you use when running the script directly has it installed.

Comment: I checked using conda: My python is 3.6.5

Comment: I was checking the package folder, and it turns out that there is multiple numpy and pandas versions in the same folder. Do you think that could be linked? @Lomtrur